# Iterative IE Navigate Issue

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to retrieve the attributes for roughly 500 CAGE codes from the DLA and record them in my spreadsheet. I've been able to get it to work for one iteration, but, on second iteration, get the error "method navigate of object iwebbrowser2 failed"

Note the code doesn't work unless you've already opened the website before and haven't closed the browser (you need to accept the terms and conditions).

The cell B2 = https://cage.dla.mil/Search/Results?q=07187&page=1
The cell B3 = https://cage.dla.mil/Search/Results?q=00198&page=1

```
Sub NSCM2()

'Initialize
Dim IE As Object
Dim CAGE As String
Dim rowNeeded As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim sDD0 As String
Dim sDD1 As String
Dim sDD2 As String
Dim sDD3 As String
Dim sDD4 As String
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument

'Create IE Object
Set IE = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.APPLICATION")

'Loop for All Codes
For i = 1 To 10

  'Retrieve CAGE Code
  rowNeeded = CStr(i + 1)
  CAGE = Range("B" & rowNeeded).Value

'Navigate to Cage Code general Page
IE.navigate CAGE

  'Wait
  Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = 4
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

  'Follow link to details page
  For Each ele In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
      If InStr(ele.innerText, "Details") > 0 Then ele.Click
  Next

  'Wait
  Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = 4
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

  'Pull needed values
  Set Doc = IE.document

  sDD0 = Doc.getElementsByTagName("span")(11).innerText
  sDD1 = Doc.getElementsByTagName("span")(15).innerText
  sDD2 = Doc.getElementsByTagName("span")(17).innerText
  sDD3 = Doc.getElementsByTagName("span")(19).innerText
  sDD4 = Doc.getElementsByTagName("span")(20).innerText

  'Close IE
  IE.Quit

  'Insert URL
  Range("F" & rowNeeded) = sDD0

  'Insert Address, comma separated
  If sDD1 = "" And sDD2 = "" And sDD3 = "" Then
    Range("G" & rowNeeded) = sDD4
    ElseIf sDD1 = "" And sDD2 = "" Then
    Range("G" & rowNeeded) = sDD3 & ", " & sDD4
    ElseIf sDD1 = "" And sDD3 = "" Then
    Range("G" & rowNeeded) = sDD2 & ", " & sDD4
    ElseIf sDD1 = "" Then
    Range("G" & rowNeeded) = sDD2 & "," & sDD3 & ", " & sDD4
    Else
    Range("G" & rowNeeded) = sDD1 & ", " & sDD2 & ", " & sDD3 & ", " & sDD4
    End If

  'Insert Address Check
  Range("H" & rowNeeded) = sDD1 & ";" & sDD2 & ";" & sDD3 & ";" & sDD4

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You create `IE` but you don't send it to a URL?  Also -you're quitting IE *inside the loop*, so the second time around it will be gone.

Comment: Sorry, when removing commented-out code, I accidentally removed the code in question: "IE.navigate CAGE". I want to prevent 500 windows of IE being open at the end, so I used QUIT inside the loop. Do you recommend something different?

Answer (score 1):

The first time through the loop, you call

```
IE.Quit
```

so your loop will fail on the second iteration

Comment: Do you have a recommended command to prevent 500 pages from being open at the loop?

Comment: After some checks, I realized that if I never set it to visible, I won't have to worry about the windows popping up. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it.